# generate constructor using fields

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) I use this shortcut for generating constructor :
`Right click → Source → generate constructor using fields`,
so Eclipse show fields and I select fields.

**What is the shortcut for Android Studio ?**

Comment: You should try alt+insert to have all code template.

Comment: Tnx dear very useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the <kbd>alt</kbd>+ <kbd>insert</kbd> combination to get all the insertion templates.

For more information, you can have a look at the [Intellij documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/generating-constructors.html) since Android Studio is based on [intellij](/questions/tagged/intellij).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but it doesn't work for constructors. Basically you are not answering the questions, again..., I might be wrong

Comment: regarding the comment from @Amir-daraei saying that it was "very useful" I think it answers its question.

Comment: When typing [alt]+[insert] I can see nothing related to the constructor, even if the name of the class is selected, dunno maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: It works with me if I select Code | Generate from the main menu, in this way I have the option to create the constructor. Not If I use the shortcut [Alt] + [Insert]

Comment: alt+insert within the code opens up a "Generate" popup for me, which has as first Element a constructor

Comment: Any shortcut for  **kotlin Constructors**? Alt + Ins not showing me generate Constructors.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac it's `command + n` , its show option like constructor, getters and setters etc .